# Are JPA's persist and merge vulnerable to sql injection?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, sql-injection

For example, if I have code like what is featured below to add a new user, is it vulnerable to SQL injection? The user object has been created from user input (i.e. name, email, password). I've used parameterized queries for my getUser method but I wasn't sure about merge and persist.

```
public static void addUser(User user) {

    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    trans.begin();        
    try {
        em.persist(user);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        trans.rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: JDBC uses parameters to inhibit that. So a JPA implementation is no more prone to it as a JDBC application.